# sed replace character only between two known strings

Tags: regex, shell, sed

Is it possible to replace a character between two known strings only? I have a number of files in the format

`title.header.index.subtitle.goes.here.footer`

I can pick out the "subtitle.goes.here" with pattern matching between the index (which I need to backreference) and a footer (which is constant), but I then want to replace the period/dot character with an underscore, to give me

`title.header.index.subtitle_goes_here.footer`

So from input such as

`title.header.01.the.first.subtitle.is.here.footer`

I want to end up with

`title.header.01.the_first_subtitle_is_here.footer`

What I have so far is useless, but a start:
`sed -r 's/([0-9][0-9]\.)([a-z]*\.*)*footer/\1footer/g'`

But this is removing the entire subtitle and footer before manually adding it back in and has plenty of other flaws I'm sure. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
echo "title.header.01.the.first.subtitle.is.here.footer" |
sed 's/\./_/4g;s/.\(footer\)/.\1/'
title.header.01.the_first_subtitle_is_here.footer
```

An ugly alternative:

```
sed 'h;s/\([0-9][0-9]\.\).*\(\.footer\)/\1\n\2/;x;s/.*[0-9][0-9]\.\(.*\).footer/\1/;s/\./_/g;x;G;s/\(\n\)\(.*\)\1\(.*\)/\3\2/' file
```

Comment: That is perfect, exactly what I was after. Thanks a lot for such a quick reply, much appreciated!

Comment: Please explain the first part !

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to `awk` solution then this might help -

```
awk '
{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (i!=NF) {printf (3<i && i<(NF-1))?$i"_":$i"."} print $NF}
' FS='.' OFS='.' file
```

#### Input File:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file
title.header.index.subtitle.goes.here.footer
title.header.01.the.first.subtitle.is.here.footer
```

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk '
{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (i!=NF) {printf (3<i && i<(NF-1))?$i"_":$i"."} print $NF}
' FS='.' OFS='.' file 
title.header.index.subtitle_goes_here.footer
title.header.01.the_first_subtitle_is_here.footer
```

Comment: This works too, many thanks for the awk alternative - I'll play around with this to learn a bit more. Thanks again!